# Unity app frames are dropping on BlueStacks

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluestacks

I created a simple test app

Nothing but one UI animation (Target frame set to 60)

After building, I ran it on BlueStacks.

Frame is abnormal in BlueStacks

Initially, it maintains 60 frames, but

It changed to 29~30 frames irregularly.

In the profiler the Semaphore.WaitForSignal marker is taking up more than 18ms

I tried changing various settings, but it didn't work.

Is there any solution to this problem?

[60frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxwoU.png)

[30frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSloi.png)

The version used was Unity 2022.3.16f1.

I made a test app because Frame was dropped only in BlueStacks.

Even in apps where there is nothing, 30 frames occur irregularly.

Comment: what is "bluestacks"?

Comment: It was a typo
this is BlueStacks app player.

Comment: @BugFinder basically an android emulator ... OP, why use BlueStacks if you can directly use the Windows Subsystem for Android? In my experience (from 5 years ago) BlueStacks was always quite clunky

Comment: I was going to say unity tends to run hardware fairly hard. So running it in something else you are limiting it to the capability of that whatever it is.

Comment: Did you try to disable the  Optimized Frame Pacing on the Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation?

Comment: @Lotan Improved frame rates by disabling Optimized Frame Rate , 
thank you!